# Not able to make mSuperdrive and mBeam API Calls in the Postman Collection

Tags: edgeengine

I am trying to make **mSuperdriv**e and **mBeam API** Calls as in the Smart-car-use case ( [ Group C – Car 1] in the postman Collection). When I made the [C1] → mSuperdrive LOCAL DISCOVERY api call (to see the Link Local clustering) I can find both of my devices in the response object,
but along with the response I am getting the following error.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error coming from postman's "Tests" tab, we have put some code in there to extract data from response body in order to set environment variables. If you are getting a 200 OK response with your devices showing you can simply ignore this error. You can also comment out the code in "Test" tab and you will not see the error for that call again. Please periodically check [here](https://developer.mimik.com/smart-car-use-case/) for new updates to the collection that will fix these issues in the future.